# How can I try Google Places API from my browser?

Tags: api, google-maps

So I would like to try the API Google Places before put it in my code... wanna check out first if that is what I need.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

So this is the link which im trying to test about, I am using my own key that I created from the console. I follow all the stepes but still im getting the error 'REQUEST_DENIED'.

Steps:
-Create my project.
-Select the Google Places Web Service Api and enabled it.
-Go to credentials, new API Key
-Browser key type
-And got it.

Any clues?

Comment: Use a server key for the web service, as stated in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a server key for the web service, as stated in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key):

> **Get a key for Google Places API Web Service**
>
> 1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=places_backend&keyType=SERVER_SIDE&reusekey=true).
> 2. Create or select a project.
> 3. Click **Continue** to Enable the API.
> 4. **Go to Credentials** to get a **Server key** (and set the API credentials).
> 5. To prevent quota theft, secure your API key following these [best practices](https://developers.google.com/console/help/console#apikeybestpractices).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there is no convenient UI for just querying it from the web. Instead, just consult the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests) documentation, and paste a query of the following style, for example, into your browser address bar.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY&inputtype=textquery&input=Starbucks